# How can I check if a variable is inside a list during a for loop in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

first time posting here. I've a feeling that this is a *really* dumb question, but for some reason my code keeps failing and I just can't put my finger on what's wrong.

Here's is what I have:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  String
Library  Collections


*** Test Cases ***
Test Robot Framework Logging
    @{ALLOWED}=  Create List  /page1  /page2  /page3
    ${ControllersList}=  Get File   ${EXEC_DIR}/Resources/controllers.txt
    @{PAGES}=  Split to lines  ${ControllersList}
    :FOR  ${PAGE}  IN  @{PAGES}
    \  Run Keyword If  '${PAGE} IN @{ALLOWED}'  Log  Testing  WARN
    [Teardown]  Close Browser
```

This is the output:

```
Evaluating expression ''/page1 IN [u'/page1', u'/page2', u'/page3']'' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

If I change the condition to something like this it works:

```
'${PAGE} == /page1'
```

I checked the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) and it seems that the IN condition could be used. I'm totally lost here. Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the proper way to do the expression:

```
Run Keyword If  $PAGE in $ALLOWED  Log  Testing  WARN
```

By removing the quotes and the curly braces, robot is able to treat PAGE and ALLOWED as python variables when evaluating the expression.

From the section [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) in the documentation for the [BuiltIn library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html):

> Starting from Robot Framework 2.9, variables themselves are automatically available in the evaluation namespace. They can be accessed using special variable syntax without the curly braces like $variable. These variables should never be quoted, and in fact they are not even replaced inside strings.

Also, when using keywords like `Run Keyword If`, the expression must be a valid python expression after variable substitution. Therefore, you must use the operator `in` rather than `IN`. The latter is used only by the robot `:FOR` statement.

### Example

```
*** Variables ***
@{ALLOWED}  /page1  /page2  /page3

*** Test Cases ***
Example that passes
    ${PAGE}=  set variable  /page1
    Run Keyword If  $PAGE in $ALLOWED
    ...  pass execution  ${PAGE} is allowed
    fail  ${PAGE} is not allowed

Example that fails
    ${PAGE}=  set variable  /page99
    Run Keyword If  $PAGE in $ALLOWED
    ...  pass execution  ${PAGE} is allowed
    fail  ${PAGE} is not allowed
```

Comment: Awesome! That works! I'm completely new to this automation stuff, and I would like very much to do things in the proper way. Thank you for your reply! Appreciate it!

Comment: The only addition I would make is that if there is a space in the variable's name it should be represented by an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

The check was almost right, but you've effectively turned the Boolean expression into a String by surrounding it with the quotes. Here's the syntax that'll do it:

```
\  Run Keyword If    $PAGE in $ALLOWED    Log  Testing  WARN
```

Mind there are no curly brackets `{}` around the variable names - thus the check is (almost) the straight python's `variable in another_variable`

Comment: can you update your answer with a working example? I've adapted the example in the previous answer and replaced the FOR content with your suggestion and sadly was unable to get the desired effect. In stead i get the error:  `FAIL : Evaluating expression 'RF_VAR_PAGE IN  RF_VAR_ALLOWED' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)`

Comment: This won't work. The proper operator is `in`, not `IN`.

Comment: Ah the troubles of typing in mobile :) sorry for the confusion, it must be `in` - lower case

Comment: Changing `$PAGE IN $ALLOWED` to `$PAGE in $ALLOWED` indeed worked for me as well.

Comment: Glad it did Xour :)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) does indeed specify that `in` construction used in the evaluation itself. An alternative approach is to use the [Collections library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html) keyword [Get Match Count](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Get%20Match%20Count). This will return 0 when no results are found, and not generate a test failure.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Test Robot Framework Logging
    @{ALLOWED}=  Create List  /page1  /page2  /page3
    @{PAGES}=  Create List  /page1  /page3  /page5
    :FOR  ${PAGE}  IN  @{PAGES}
    \    ${InList}=    Get Match Count    ${ALLOWED}    ${PAGE}
    \    Run Keyword If  ('${InList}' == '0')    Log To Console    Page Not Allowed
    \    ...    ELSE IF  ('${InList}' == '1')    Log To Console    1 Page Found
    \    ...    ELSE                             Log To Console    More pages found.
```

Comment: I totally missed that, used uppercase IN instead of lowercase. Also, what Bryan Oakley mentioned about the curly bracers and quotes. Thanks!